# Capacity Exceeded Error in executing INSERT command

Tags: c#, sql-insert

I'm working on Visual Studio2012 C# with an MS Access2010 DataBase. I was trying to make an insert and it was giving me an error saying the datatype of the fields was wrong so I started going one by one and on the second got the "Capacity Exceeded error". Tried googling it, can't find anything. The error comes up on the **result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();**

```
    public int insertEquipamento(string codigo, int visivel, string freqCal, string fornecedor,
        string modelo, string nSerie, string gamaMedida, DateTime dataAquis, string resolucao,
        string criterioAceit, string marca)
    {
        OleDbConnection l = OleDbConnectionDAO.createConnection();
        int result = 0;

        try
        {
            l.Open();

            OleDbCommand cmd = l.CreateCommand();


            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@Codigo", codigo));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@visivel", visivel));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@Fabricante", fornecedor));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@Modelo", modelo));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@NumSerie", nSerie));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@DataAq", dataAquis));
            //cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@Entidade", entidadeCal));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@GamaMedida", gamaMedida));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@Precisao", resolucao));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@FreqCal", freqCal));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@critAceit", criterioAceit));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@marca", marca));



            cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [Tabela Equipamentos 2012] (" +

                "Codigo, [Plano Calibração]" +
                //", Fabricante, Modelo, [NúmeroDeSérie]"+
                //", [Data Aquisição],  [Gama Medida] "+
               // ", [Precisão], [Frequência Calibração], [Critério Aceitação], marca" +

                ") "+
                "VALUES " +
                "( " +

                "'@Codigo', '@visivel'" +
                //", '@Fabricante', '@Modelo', '@NumSerie'"+
                //", '@DataAq', '@GamaMedida' " +
                //", '@Precisao', '@FreqCal', '@critAceit', '@marca'" +

                ")";

             result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();  
            l.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            l.Close();
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("DAO Exception: " + ex.Message);
            return result;
        }
        return result;
    }
```

The that second variable "*visivel*" is a int that holds either the value 1 or 0. I've tried replacing *@visivel* on the *CommandText* with **?**, with **0** and with **1** and when it's the quest mark it also shows that error, but if it's either of the numbers it runs without any issue (I've checked the values in debug, the *visivel* variable is either 1 or 0). 
So why is this error showing up and waht can i do to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to Add `Single Quote` for parameters :

Try This:

```
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [Tabela Equipamentos 2012] (Codigo, [Plano Calibração]) VALUES (@Codigo, @visivel)";
```

And you need to Add the `Command Parameters` which are specified in `Command String`

```
 cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@Codigo", codigo));
 cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@visivel", visivel));
```

Comment: Need to add the *Command Parameters*? I have that for every parameter, even the ones commented, right befroe the *CommandText*

Comment: you need to add the command parameters for only parameters specified in command string , here you have used only 2 params and commented remianing so you need to add only 2 parameters using  `cmd.Parameters.Add()` statement as mentioned in my answer

Comment: So I can get an error for adding parameters without using them in the command string?